# Role of const for a C array of string literals

Tags: c, arrays, constants, string-literals

I would like to test the roles of the two 'const' specifiers in the following initialization of a C array of string literals:

```
const char* const myArray[] = { "one", "two", "three" };
```

I have read previous questions on SO, and understood that the *second* const means that the elements of the array cannot be changed, which I interpret as the addresses contained in the pointers myArray[0], etc, must not change.  So, when this 'const' is present,

```
myArray[0] = "uno";
```

does not compile ("error: assignment of read-only location 'myArray[0]'") but when removing it the assignment works fine.

However, I cannot find a similar example illustrating the role of the *first* 'const' above, which should mean that the literals of myArray cannot themselves be changed (but how could they change anyway?).  I tried something like this:

```
myArray[0][0] = 'u';
```

and when the first 'const' is present I get a compilation error ("error: assignment of read-only location '*(myArray[0])'") but without it I get a "run failed" with NetBeans and MinGW.

Could someone please provide a better example for the role of the first 'const' above ? Many thanks.

Comment: Literal strings are *read only* in C. You can not modify them, attempting to do so will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: `myArray` is not an array

Comment: If you actually wanted `myArray` to be an array, it needs to be declared as `const char* const myArray[] = { "one", "two", "three" };`

Comment: Sorry for the typo (which I nw corrected), indeed I meant myArray[], and the behavior I described was tested with myArray[].

Comment: @andreipb I have corrected my answer to accommodate the change you made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your declaration `const char* const myArray[]` expands to -

> an array of constant pointer to const characters

Which means, it is an array of pointers which are constant, so cannot be changed once initialized. And the characters it points to are also constant, meaning you can dereference the pointer to only read the characters but cannot overwrite them.

This array is being initialized to an array containing three strings `"one"`, `"two"` and `"three"`.

So the operations like

```
myArray[i] = ...;
*myArray[i] = ...;
```

would fail, but operations like -

```
otherArray = myArray[i];
char t = *myArray[i];
```

would be fine.

This is also the reason why code like `myArray[0] = "uno"` doesn't compile.

You are trying to assign a new string to `myArray[0]`, but it is declared as a `const` (the `const` that comes after the `*` causes this).

Now coming to your question about `myArray[0][0] = 'u';`. Even if you remove the first `const`, string literals are by default `const`. You cannot change the characters they contain. The compiler doesn't complain about assignment because it doesn't know that `myArray[0]` is pointing to a constant string.

This is an issue with the C standard, that the string literals have a type `char*` and not `const char*`. This cannot be changed now because of lot of legacy code that uses this would break.

Comment: When you declare an array, the second const is unnecessary, since you can't change where the variable points to. `const char* myArray[]` is enough.

Comment: @JorgeBellón no, `const char* const myArray[]` and `const char* myArray[]` are different; the later allows you to change the elements of the array but the first one doesn't after it is initialized.

Comment: With `const char* myArray[]` it would be perfectly fine to pass `myArray` to `qsort` for sorting the strings within the array.

Comment: Thank you @AjayBrahmakshatriya and sorry for the typo, I really meant myArray[].  So what I really take as the answer to my question is the last two paragraphs.  I would conclude that with an array of strings, the first const is not really meaningful.  Things would be different with an array of numbers, though.

Comment: @andreipb, yes the last para is the most important to your question. No it's not every character array that is by default constant. It is only the character pointers that point to a string literal. If you make a character array or malloc memory for a char pointer and then copy the string to it, it is not const by default.

Comment: It is only the literals like `"abcd"` that are constan